# Interpreting significance in hierarchical regression

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, interpretation

I've run a Hierarchical Multiple Regression to understand the unique predictive value of three different maternal variables (maternal PTSD, maternal depression, and quality of the parent-child relationship) in child behavior following trauma exposure (measured by two different subscales of Externalizing behavior problems and Internalizing behavior problems).

Based on theory, I decided to enter the variables in the following order and ran the regression twice (once with externalizing behavior as the DV and once with the internalizing behavior as the DV):

1. Child's age & sex
2. Number of traumatic events child experienced
3. Maternal PTSD symptoms score
4. Maternal Depressive symptoms score
5. Quality of parent-child relationship

I also included some interaction terms in a sixth step but they were not significant so I dropped them from the model.

In the final model, both maternal depression and the quality of the parent-child relationship had significant standardized beta coefficients, and change in R squared was also significant for both the externalizing and internalizing subscales. This would allow me to conclude that the quality of the parent-child relationship uniquely predicts child behavior following trauma exposure, controlling for child age, sex, trauma history, maternal PTSD and maternal depressive symptoms. But how do I interpret the fact that Maternal Depressive symptoms remain significant after the addition of the last step variable (parent-child relationship)? (How would I explain that in plain English?)

Comment: Where does the hierarchical part of the model come in?  Is it that some mothers have more than one child?

Comment: What is wrong with "After controlling for child age, sex, trauma history and maternal PTSD, significant evidence was found that both maternal depressive symptoms and quality of parent-child relationship were related to child behvior following trauma exposure".  Perhaps it relates to what you mean by "uniquely predicts", which I don't quite understand.